# Android RAM: how to ensure an app does not get closed

Tags: ram

My understanding about android RAM management: when you press the home button, the app goes in the background, it does not actually get closed. The app only get closed when the Android OS decides that it is time to free up some RAM (e.g. because you are launching an app that needs a lot of memory).

I have a device with 4GB of RAM (Huawei P9 plus), but Android start closing apps when there is still 1.5GB of RAM free.

In particular, this is troublesome for Dosbox (where you cannot save your progress easily). So I would like to ensure that Android only closes dosbox when it really needs the RAM.

Is there anyway to do this? Either by prioritizing which app get closed first, or by stipulating at which RAM level apps get closed. Note: I cannot root my phone, but an option which involves root would be better than nothing.

Thanks, Serge